# MDX Calculated Measure to get Cumulative Sum from First Month to Last Month of each year

Tags: ssas, mdx, ssas-2012, mdx-query, mdxstudio

I would like to get Cumulative Sum from Jan - Dec for each year

Something similar to Below But replace First Month and Last Month with the current year data. I have data from 2014 -2017

`Sum(
   [Ship Date].[Date].CURRENT_MEMBER.FirstMonth
 : [Ship Date].[Date].CURRENT_MEMBER.LastMonth,[Measures].[Revenue]
)`

Comment: Do you not have a year hierarchy within your date dimension?

Comment: Yes, year and month hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use this structure which I’ve taken from the MSDN YTD page:

```
WITH MEMBER MEASURES.YTDDEMO AS
AGGREGATE(YTD(), [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])
SELECT {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount], MEASURES.YTDDEMO} ON 0,
[Date].[Calendar].MEMBERS ON 1
FROM [Adventure Works]
```

Here is another alternative:

```
Aggregate(

     PeriodsToDate( 
           [Date].[Calendar Hierarchy].[Year],
           [Date].[Calendar Hierarchy].CurrentMember 
     ),
     [Measures].[Sales]
 )
```

Comment: This didn't work. Am I missing anything                                                                            Aggregate(

     PeriodsToDate( 
            [MonthEnd].[Month_End].[Year],
            [MonthEnd].[Month_End].CurrentMember 
     ),
     [Measures].[TransAmt]
 )

Comment: Month_End is the Hierarchy name and Year,Month,date is the hierarchy order